# what's going on with my internet speed?

Tags: internet

what's going on with my internet speed? sometimes it goes fast as lightning(it downloaded 1 gb in 60 minutes) and sometimes it's as slow as a snail. please don't talk about plans and stuff as I am only 13 and only need an answer.
thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fischer mabe if you see my other posts, you will know that I am more in computers than just a 13 year old. I know python programming and work on linux. I would appreciate it if you stop saying these things to me. :(

Comment: @Fischer 13 year olds (boys _and_ girls) are welcome as long as they ask good questions. While this is indeed not a good question and deserves a downvote (@user2508947, it is not a good question because it does not ask for a solution to a specific problem and it is very hard to answer because it is too general, see [here](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)), there is no age restriction on SE. There are many 13 year old wizz kids that know a good deal more than I do about computers. In any case, SU is _not_ for professionals, in fact, questions about professional IT networks are off topic.

Comment: @terdon Thank you. I will take what you said about general posting into mind. :)

Comment: @user2508947 deleted my comment, apologies :)

Comment: @Fischer ok. apology accepted. :)

Comment: @terdon thank you for editing my post. I really appreciate it, but I want people to know not to talk about plans and such. You can edit it again, but just include the stuff about plans. but thank you :)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by plans, that's why I removed it but it's your post, keep it as you like :).

Comment: @terdon I saw it on other internet stuff I searched on google. I think it's something about payments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your internet speed depends on many things including:

- The time of day; your internet service provider (ISP) is slower when many people are connected and downloading at once. You will observe speed fluctuations based on server load.
- The server you are downloading from; the speed you can achieve depends on how fast you can receive data but also on how fast the server you are connecting to can send data. Downloading from slower servers means a slower connection speed.
- Some ISPs restrict bandwidth when connected to specific sites or downloading certain types of files.

That you are getting different speeds when downloading from different servers does not mean that your internet speed is fluctuating. To test your internet speed, use a dedicated test server, http://www.speedtest.net/, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The first few things that come to my mind are:

- Multiple devices on the local network can cause the bandwidth available from your modem to each individual device to decrease.
- Running many network heavy programs, downloading many files, and uploading many files all at the same time can cause the bandwidth available from your modem to each individual program to decrease.
- The amount of traffic on your ISP (internet service provider).
- The amount of traffic on the server from which you are getting the data.

There could be many other reasons, but these are just a few that were on the top of my head.